# Python Writing To CSV All in One Cell

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to shave the top 7 lines off a csv file.

There is probably a more concise way to do this, but right now I am reading one file and writing each line other than the first 7 to another file. When I write to the file though, all the contents for the line show up in the first cell instead of spread out in organized columns.

Here is my code:

```
with open('file1.csv', 'r') as file_org:
    with open("file2.csv","w") as file_stripped:
        writer = csv.writer(file_stripped)
        for i, line in enumerate(file_org, -7):
            if i>=0: 
                writer.writerow([line])
```

Thank you!

Comment: What You want it to skip the first 7 lines and write the rest to another file…?

Comment: You need to read it as CSV if you want to write it as CSV.

Comment: And both files have the same CSV format, right?

Comment: In deed you don’t need to read as CSV… if both files have the save format, you can just skip the first 7 lines and save the rest to destination as plain text. Simple like that.

Answer (score 0):

reading in csv do need you to specify the seperator, which is usually ";", you can find the constructor usage in manual, and you should open the file and see the content, not by some other tool like excel

if you are not meant to change the content, you could just treat them as normal files / line, or just by

```
line.split(";")
```

or

```
";".join(splited_line)
```

manully